# QEMU is displayed in dpkg but I cant uninstall it

Tags: apt, dpkg, qemu, software-uninstall

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 LTS on HP probook. I recently installed QEMU and now I want to uninstall it. However when I use the following command

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove qemu-system-x86_64
```

I get the following result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package qemu-system-x86_64
```

Also, when i run the command

```
qemu-system-x86_64
```

QEMU terminal opens up and starts looking for the boot device.

What is causing this, and how can I remove QEMU completely?

*Edit*
When I run the command

```
dpkg -l | grep qemu
```

I get the following response

```
ii  ipxe-qemu                                   1.0.0+git-20150424.a25a16d-1ubuntu1.2        all          PXE boot firmware - ROM images for qemu
ii  qemu-block-extra:amd64                      1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16                      amd64        extra block backend modules for qemu-system and qemu-utils
ii  qemu-system-common                          1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16                      amd64        QEMU full system emulation binaries (common files)
ii  qemu-system-x86                             1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16                      amd64        QEMU full system emulation binaries (x86)
ii  qemu-utils                                  1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16                      amd64        QEMU utilities
```

Comment: Please run `dpkg -l qemu` to see if it's really called that then use what you see to remove that package!

Comment: don't you mean `dlkg -l | grep qemu`? Anyway, on my system it is called `qemu-system-x86`.

Comment: Yes DougSmythies that would be a better command to run do `dpkg -l | grep qemu` to get the real name!

Comment: Thank you all very much. The problem has been solved by suggestion of George Udosen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was solved by first checking the exact name of the package by using

```
dpkg -l | grep qemu
```

and then running

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove qemu-system-x86
```

Thanks for comments